# R: ifelse statement: comparing data.frames

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes where im trying to compare the value in one with another
If the value matches in both table 1 and 2, then a third value from table 2 is inserted into Table one.

Example **Table My DF**

```
    words number
 1      it      1
 2     was      2
 3     the      3
 4     LTD QTY  4
 5     end      5
 6      of      6
 7  winter      7
```

Table x.sub

```
   lev_dist    Var1    Var2
31        1 LTD QTY LTD QTY
```

What i want to say is, if Var1 in x.sub is equal to words in MyDF then insert x.sub.lev_dist in a third column next to the word in mydf

My attempt is below but keeps producing 3 in the results instead of the lev_value

```
mydf$lev_dist <- ifelse(test = (mydf$words == x.sub$Var1),x.sub$Var1,0)
```

Results:

```
    words number lev_dist
1      it      1        0
2     was      2        0
3     the      3        0
4 LTD QTY      4        3
5     end      5        0
6      of      6        0
7  winter      7        0
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Check if x.sub$Var1 is factor.  In that case, try `as.character(x.sub$Var1), 0)`

Comment: You are absolutely correct...That was a very bad mistake to make but thank you for picking it up...Final Answer is: mydf$lev_dist <- ifelse(test = (mydf$words == as.character(x.sub$Var1)),x.sub$lev_dist,0)

If you can show me how to mark your answer i will do it

Comment: You could also try solve it *efficiently* using the `data.table` package and its binary join, something along these lines `library(data.table); temp <- setkey(setDT(x.sub[1:2]), Var1); temp[mydf]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x.sub$Var1` is a `factor` column.  So, when we do the `ifelse`, we get the numeric `levels` of the factor.  Replace `x.sub$Var1` with `as.character(x.sub$Var1)` in the `ifelse`

```
 mydf$lev_dist <- ifelse(mydf$words == as.character(x.sub$Var1)),
                        x.sub$lev_dist,0)
```

This could have avoided if the columns were of `character` class.  Using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv/read.table` or `data.frame` would ensure that all the character columns are of `character` class.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `merge`:

```
x.sub = setNames(x.sub,c('lev_dist','words','Var2'))

df_ = merge(df, x.sub[,1:2], by='words', all=T)
df_[is.na(df_)]=0

# >df_
#    words number lev_dist
#1     end      5        0
#2      it      1        0
#3 LTD QTY      4        1
#4      of      6        0
#5     the      3        0
#6     was      2        0
#7  winter      7        0
```