# R: ifelse statement test involving multiple dataframes

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a new variable using `ifelse` by combining data from two `data.frames` (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145342/r-ifelse-statement-comparing-data-frames) question but without factors).

My problem is that `df1` features yearly data, whereas vars in `df2` are temporally aggregated: e.g. `df1` has multiple obs (1997,1998,...,2005) and `df2` only has a range (1900-2001).

For illustration, a 2x2 example would look like

```
df1$id <- c("2","20")
df1$year <- c("1960","1870")

df2$id <- df1$id
df2$styear <- c("1800","1900")
df2$endyear <- c("2001","1950")
```

I want to combine both in such a way that the id (same variable exists in both) is matched, and further, the year in `df1` is within the range of `df2`. I tried the following

```
df1$new.var <- ifelse(df1$id==df2$id & df1$year>=df2$styear & 
df1$year<df2$endyear,1,0)
```

Which ideally should return 1 and 0, respectively.

But instead I get warning messages:

> 1: In df1$id == df2$id :   longer object length is not a multiple of
>   shorter object length
>
> 2: In df1$year >= df2$styear :   longer object length is not a
>   multiple of shorter object length
>
> 3: In df1$year < df2$endyear :   longer object length is not a
>   multiple of shorter object length

For the record, the 'real' `df1` has 500 obs and `df2` has 14. How can I make this work?

Edit: I realised some obs in `df2` are repeated, with multiple periods e.g.

```
id    styear    endyear
1      1800      1915
1      1950      2002
2      1912      1988
3      1817      2000
```

So, I believe what I need is something like a double-ifelse:

```
df1$new.var <- ifelse(df1$id==df2$id & df1$year>=df2$styear & 
df1$year<df2$endyear | df1$year>=df2$styear & 
df1$year<df2$endyear,1,0)
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work, but it is a way to get out of the duplicates-problem.

For example, if `id=1` in `df1$year=1801`, it will pass the first year-range test (1801 is between 1800-1915), but fail the second one (1801 is not between 1950-2002), so it is only coded once and no extra rows are added (currently the duplicates add extra rows).

Comment: see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.9.6/topics/foverlaps

Comment: @Bulat Hello, foverlaps was recommended by others too, I can't seem to get it to work - says "Duplicate columns are not allowed in overlap joins. This may change in the future."

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example please.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1$id <- c("2","20")
df1$year <- c("1960","1870")

df2$id <- df1$id
df2$styear <- c("1800","1900")
df2$endyear <- c("2001","1950")

library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df1,df2,by = "id") %>% filter(year <= endyear,year >= startyear)
```

I highly recommend the dplyr package for data manipulation.

Comment: dplyr is great indeed, wish I was better at it. Re: your answer, this does work in the sense that the identification is executed correctly when it is "1", but the resulting dataset is only a subset of the original - the "0" cases are listwise deleted. Is there a way to keep df1 intact?

Comment: Strangely enough, going from inner_join to left_join did not have an effect - still losing all the obs with 0.

Comment: try flipping around the order of the data frames in the argument

Comment: Changing the order did not have any effect either, still losing around half. However, it led me to reading about dplyr more and now I found a solution of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

With base R:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(2,20,22), year=c(1960,1870, 2016))
df2 <- data.frame(id=c(2,20,21), styear=c(1800,1900,2000), endyear=c(2001,1950,2016))

df1
id year
1  2 1960
2 20 1870
3 22 2016

df2

id styear endyear
1  2   1800    2001
2 20   1900    1950
3 21   2000    2016

df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by='id', all.x = TRUE)
df1$new.var <- !is.na(df1$styear) & df1$year>=df1$styear & df1$year< df1$endyear
df1 <- df1[c('id', 'year', 'new.var')]

df1
  id year new.var
1  2 1960    TRUE
2 20 1870   FALSE
3 22 2016   FALSE
```

Comment: This is more in line with what I have in mind. One thing though - I have repeating id-year combinations in df1 - the code does well when there is no duplicates, but results in a rotating TRUE/FALSE in some cases. Thoughts?

Comment: Can we have the unique id-year pairs from the df1 selected  first, then create the new-var. Once creaated, the duplicate id-years from df1 that were left out, will exactly have same new.var value, so if you have count of the duplicate id-year pairs, it will just be a matter of replicating / adding them (e.g., with rbind).

Comment: I created id-years, but still can't get around the problem of matching. Have you seen the edit at the end of my question? I think that is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I made it work for myself. Beware, it is quite convoluted and probably contain some redundancies. After a brief look at the data wrangling [cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf), assuming you have `df1` and `df2` with an identical `var` and `df2` contains `new.var`, one can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
#Join everything, all values and rows
df3 <- full_join(df1,df2,by="id")
#filter out obs those year is greater than endyear
df3 <- filter(df3,df3$year<=df3$endyear)
#same, the other way around
df3 <- filter(df3,df3$year>=df3$styear) 
df3 <- distinct(df3) #remove duplicate rows (at least I had some)
```

As far as I can tell by looking at the end result, this method only extracts information from the correct time period while dropping all other time periods in `df2`. Then, it is a matter of merging with the original data.frame (`df1`) and filling in the NAs:

```
df1 <- merge(df1,df3,by=(id),all.x=TRUE)
df1 <- distinct(df1) #just to make sure, I still had three
df1$new.var <- ifelse(is.na(df1$new.var),0,df1$new.var)
```

which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily and efficiently using non-equi joins in `data.table` [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (1.9.7+):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2) # converting to data.table in place

df1[, new.var := df2[df1, on = .(id, styear <= year, endyear >= year),
                     .N > 0, by = .EACHI]$V1]
df1
#   id year new.var
#1:  2 1960    TRUE
#2: 20 1870   FALSE
```

The above join looks for matches in `df2` for each row of `df1` (`by = .EACHI`), and checks the number of matching rows (`.N`).

Comment: This sounds brilliant, however currently does not give me the same results you got - I tried it both on my actual data and on @sandipan's mwe, both give the same warning: Error in `[.data.table`(df2, df1, on = list(id, styear <= year, endyear >=  : object 'styear' not found

Comment: @rfsrc start over in a new R session (and make sure you have installed the devel version).

Comment: Okay, now a bit better after removing the package and installing the devel. So, now it definitely works on the mwe, but it still gives an error with the actual data: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'styear' not found. I'm quite sure there's a styear in my df2, tried changing class but still no difference.

Comment: @rfsrc I'm not sure how to help you unfortunately without a reproducible example