# Matching two column in r

Tags: r

I am new to r and unsure how to use it, I had two column the first one is question key, and the second is Response column. I want to write a code that allow me to do that.

```
Question.Key   Response
Charmed        charmed
Freedom        freedom
Obstinat       obstinate
Exact          likeness
```

Basically I want r to create a new column if the Response match the question key to write True as an example of row 1,2 and 3, and if it doesn't match it write False as in row 4.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: ifelse statement: comparing data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145342/r-ifelse-statement-comparing-data-frames)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double equal sign `==` to compare two columns, but the comparison is case-sensitive, so "Charmed" would *not* be equal to "charmed". In this example, I first convert everything to lower case, then I create a new column with the comparison:

```r
dat <- data.frame(Question.Key = c("Charmed", "Freedom", "Obstinat", "Exact"),
                  Response = c("charmed", "freedom", "obstinate", "likeness"))

dat$Question.Key <- tolower(dat$Question.Key)

dat$Same <- dat$Question.Key == dat$Response

dat
#>   Question.Key  Response  Same
#> 1      charmed   charmed  TRUE
#> 2      freedom   freedom  TRUE
#> 3     obstinat obstinate FALSE
#> 4        exact  likeness FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a typo with "obsinat" in Question.Key column, but if it's not, see if this works:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(Question.Key = toupper(Question.Key), Response = toupper(Response)) %>% 
+   mutate(Same = grepl(paste0(substr(Response,1,5), collapse = '|'), Question.Key))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Question.Key Response  Same 
  <chr>        <chr>     <lgl>
1 CHARMED      CHARMED   TRUE 
2 FREEDOM      FREEDOM   TRUE 
3 OBSTINAT     OBSTINATE TRUE 
4 EXACT        LIKENESS  FALSE
>
```

But if it's a typo you can remove the substr part and just use:

```
df %>% mutate(Question.Key = toupper(Question.Key), Response = toupper(Response)) %>% 
  mutate(Same = grepl(paste0(Response, collapse = '|'), Question.Key))
```