# Compare column by column in 2 data.frames with apply() and ifelse() statements to report a 1 or 0 depending on comparison

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, if-statement, apply

My objective is two-fold:

1. Compare 2 data frames (df1, df2), column by column. If any of the comparisons have a 'None' in either cell (df1 or df2), to report back a 0. If 'None' isn't in the comparison, to report back a 1. The result of this loop would be the intermediary step (please see flow diagram below).
2. A final data.frame that sums all of the results (by column and row). The total columns in this data.frame would be equal to the total columns in df1 (colnames of df1) and the total rows of this data.frame will contain (as row.names) the columns in df2 with the total sum in each cell (ex. comparison of C1-M1, C2-M2, etc). Please see #3 in flow diagram below.

I have put together a visual: a flow diagram using df1, df2 so that you can see what my objectives are and what I am aiming for my final data.frame to look like:

[image: Flow Diagram]

**Code to make df1 and df2**

```
df1 <- data.frame(C1 = c("A", "B", "None"), C2 = c("B", "A", "A"),  
              C3 = c("None", "None", "B"), row.names = paste0("Proj.", 1:3))
df2 <- data.frame(M1 = c("A", "None", "B"), M2 = c("B", "None", "B"),  
              M3 = c("A", "B", "B"), M4 = c("None", "None", "None"),  row.names = paste0("Proj.", 1:3))
```

I have searched for code at how objective 1 could be done and have found a considerable number of posts that combine an `ifelse` within the `apply` function in R, so I am starting with an `ifelse` statement, but this does not take into consideration how to include the 'None' to turn it into 0, so the results are wrong (but getting there):

```
ifelse(df1$C1 == df2[, c("M1", "M2", "M3", "M4")], 1, 0)
    M1 M2 M3 M4
Proj.1  1  0  1  0
Proj.2  0  0  1  0
Proj.3  0  0  0  1
```

This loop comes close, but I cannot figure out how the `apply` is looping. It's not C1-M1, C1-M2, C1-M3 combination, nor is it C1-M1, C2-M1, C3-M1, etc. Additionally, this does not change the 'None' to 0.

```
t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == df2, 1, 0)))
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
Proj.1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0     0     0     1
Proj.2    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1
Proj.3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1     1     0     0
```

I have taken inspiration from this particular link [R: ifelse statement: comparing data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145342/r-ifelse-statement-comparing-data-frames) that is looking for characters in an `ifelse` statement while comparing 2 data.frames. I changed all of the "None" in df1, df2 to a numeric 0 and tried again, but this gives me an error.

```
df1.1 <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(apply(df1, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == "None", 0, x)))))
df2.2 <- as.data.frame(t(unlist(apply(df2, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == "None", 0, x)))))
apply(df1.1, 1, function(x) ifelse(x == as.numeric(df2.2, 0, 1)))
```

> > Error in ifelse(x == as.numeric(df2.2, 0, 1)) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Matrix/array solution

The way your data is structured is really as matrices/arrays, not data.frames, so here's a matrix solution:

First make your data matrices and insert `NA`s for `"None"` strings:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(C1 = c("A", "B", "None"), C2 = c("B", "A", "A"),  
                  C3 = c("None", "None", "B"), row.names = paste0("Proj.", 1:3))
df2 <- data.frame(M1 = c("A", "None", "B"), M2 = c("B", "None", "B"),  
                  M3 = c("A", "B", "B"), M4 = c("None", "None", "None"),  row.names = paste0("Proj.", 1:3))

m1 <- as.matrix(df1)
m2 <- as.matrix(df2)
m1[m1 == "None"] <- NA
m2[m2 == "None"] <- NA

m1
#>        C1  C2  C3 
#> Proj.1 "A" "B" NA 
#> Proj.2 "B" "A" NA 
#> Proj.3 NA  "A" "B"
m2
#>        M1  M2  M3  M4
#> Proj.1 "A" "B" "A" NA
#> Proj.2 NA  NA  "B" NA
#> Proj.3 "B" "B" "B" NA
```

Then iterate over `proj` values, check where they're not `NA`, make a matrix for each C/M combination, and aggregate over the proj dimension:

```r
rownames(m1) |>
    # use sapply to keep names, but don't simplify
    sapply(
        # make a matrix for corresponding proj rows of m1 and m2
        function(i) outer(!is.na(m1[i, ]), !is.na(m2[i, ]), FUN = `*`), 
        simplify = FALSE
    ) |>
    simplify2array() |>
    # sum over the third (proj) dimension of the array
    apply(2:1, sum)
#>    C1 C2 C3
#> M1  1  2  1
#> M2  1  2  1
#> M3  2  3  1
#> M4  0  0  0
```

##### data.frame solution

You can also solve this problem with data.frames, but to do so it is way easier to put your data in long form.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1_long <- df1 %>%
    rownames_to_column("proj") %>%
    gather(cn, letter, -proj) %>%
    mutate(letter = na_if(letter, "None"))

df2_long <- df2 %>%
    rownames_to_column('proj') %>%
    gather(mn, letter, -proj) %>%
    mutate(letter = na_if(letter, "None"))

df1_long
#>     proj cn letter
#> 1 Proj.1 C1      A
#> 2 Proj.2 C1      B
#> 3 Proj.3 C1   <NA>
#> 4 Proj.1 C2      B
#> 5 Proj.2 C2      A
#> 6 Proj.3 C2      A
#> 7 Proj.1 C3   <NA>
#> 8 Proj.2 C3   <NA>
#> 9 Proj.3 C3      B

df2_long
#>      proj mn letter
#> 1  Proj.1 M1      A
#> 2  Proj.2 M1   <NA>
#> 3  Proj.3 M1      B
#> 4  Proj.1 M2      B
#> 5  Proj.2 M2   <NA>
#> 6  Proj.3 M2      B
#> 7  Proj.1 M3      A
#> 8  Proj.2 M3      B
#> 9  Proj.3 M3      B
#> 10 Proj.1 M4   <NA>
#> 11 Proj.2 M4   <NA>
#> 12 Proj.3 M4   <NA>
```

Then we can join on `proj`, figure out which combinations have both letters populated, and aggregate:

```r
df3 <- inner_join(
        df1_long,
        df2_long,
        by = "proj", 
        relationship = "many-to-many"
    ) %>%
    mutate(has_proj = !is.na(letter.x) & !is.na(letter.y)) %>%
    group_by(cn, mn) %>%
    summarise(n = sum(has_proj), .groups = "drop") 

df3
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    cn    mn        n
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 C1    M1        1
#>  2 C1    M2        1
#>  3 C1    M3        2
#>  4 C1    M4        0
#>  5 C2    M1        2
#>  6 C2    M2        2
#>  7 C2    M3        3
#>  8 C2    M4        0
#>  9 C3    M1        1
#> 10 C3    M2        1
#> 11 C3    M3        1
#> 12 C3    M4        0
```

If you really want, you can spread back to wide form:

```r
df3 %>% spread(cn, n, fill = 0L)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   mn       C1    C2    C3
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 M1        1     2     1
#> 2 M2        1     2     1
#> 3 M3        2     3     1
#> 4 M4        0     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for such a detailed, well written, and explained code. I have gone line by line to understand. May I ask what `apply(2:1 .. )` is doing? Based on `?apply` you're asking the function to first sum over rows, then columns? Is this why the rows and columns flip as well? 

Lastly, looking into `?spread`, it states that for the `fill = ` flag, missing values will be replaced with this value. What is `fill = 0L` doing in this case? 

Thank-you very much!

Comment: The input to `apply()` has 3 dimensions, so `2:1` indicates to keep the second and first dimensions (cols and rows) and apply the function (`sum`) over the third. And yeah, they're backwards to flip them; it's the same as `... |> apply(1:2, sum) |> t()` to transpose afterwards. Try some different inputs for the dimensions and you'll see in what dimensions you get where in the outputs.

Comment: And yeah, `fill` in spread replaces `NA`s with the specified value. But it's actually superfluous here, sorry; those values would already be zero. See also [`fill()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html), which you can use to fill in `NA`s after the fact. And it's `0L` instead of `0` because the former is an integer and the latter is a double, though it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Thank-you very much. This is incredible helpful and I learned a lot (i.e., `|>`, `apply(2:1)`, `fill = 0L`, etc.) by going over this code and looking up the commands.  I will try your suggestion to try different inputs for the dimensions for the `apply` function. Thanks, again!